# canvasjs and coingecko api data

Tags: json, charts, canvasjs, coingecko

being new to plotting chart with the external api data and lack of knowldge leads me to ask 
HOw to plot a chart with coingeko charts api data? link to get json formated api data is:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/market_chart?vs_currency=btc&days=30

i had used this sample code and replace the link however only empty chart gets populated without plotting any data points

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var dataPoints = [];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title:{
        text:"Rendering Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints : dataPoints,
    }]
});
$.getJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/mustangcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=btc&days=max&type=json", function(data) {  
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        dataPoints.push({x: value[0], y: parseInt(value[1])});
    }); 
    chart.render();
});
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The API returns:

```
{
  prices: Array,
  market_caps: Array,
  total_volumes: Array,
}
```

First you need to select which data you want, you cannot mix them up together.

Secondly, you should create chart `new CanvasJS.Chart` after you have received the JSON result (in the `function() {}` body, not before that. Right now, it is uncertain whether the chart is actually getting the updated `dataPoints`, or is aware about it being updated after you have created the chart.

If you want to update the chart after creation you need to do what their docs says: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/